# How to properly set up Vite for UI kit development? [Solved]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, uikit, vite

I decided to develop a UI kit as a pet project and ran into some issues when using Vite in library mode.  One of these problems is that Vite adds storybook files (.storybook.ts) to the final assembly, although they are not used anywhere in the main logic that Vite reaches from the entrypoint (index.ts).  And it turns out that in the final assembly there is extra code lying around.  The second problem is that the fonts that I use in the project and include in SCSS are placed in the final assembly in the CSS file in a place separate from it (somewhere in assets).  Because of this, my CSS file, instead of weighing 10-20 kilobytes, having only styles in itself, weighs 4.300 kilobytes, including fonts and styles.  The third problem is that the final build ends up with one large CSS file instead of splitting the CSS between the components.  And it turns out that if the end user wants to use some simple Button component, then all the styles from the UI kit will get into the final assembly of his project, which can seriously affect the size of the final web application.

While I was dealing with these and other problems, I looked through a lot of information about them.  Similar questions that have been on this and other forums at best solved a small part of the problem, and those questions that I really needed an answer to remained without a proper answer or without it for months.  Here is the configuration I have now:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

import dts from 'vite-plugin-dts'

import path from 'path'

export default defineConfig({

    plugins: [dts()],

    build: {

        lib: {

            entry: 'src/index.ts',

            name: 'kuui',

            fileName: 'index',

        },

        rollupOptions: {

            external: ['react'],

            output: {

                globals: {

                    react: 'react',

                },

            },

        },

    },

    resolve: {

        alias: {

            '@': path.resolve('./src'),

        },

    },

})
```

GitHub(https://github.com/ManucherKM/kuui)

Edit:
I solved the problem, everything turned out to be much simpler.  It was necessary to disable unnecessary side effects.  The images show the result of the build before and after it was disabled.  Well, as you can see from the results, the size of the css file has decreased by 90 percent. You may think “it’s only ~19KB smaller,” but with the development of the whale’s UI, this difference will only become larger.  Just for reference, I was able to solve the problem while I was tinkering with Ant Design's source code.  That's all I wanted to say.  I wrote to close the topic.
[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7ufI.jpg), [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEJdE.jpg), [code added to package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjYi2.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I only have an answer for your first problem, you could add an `exclude` array to the dts plugin options

```
dts({
      include: ['src/components/', 'src/index.ts'],
      exclude: [
        'src/components/**/*.stories.tsx',
        'src/components/**/*.styles.ts',
      ],
    }),
```